# Need help with creating inital JAX-WS project

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

I'm stepping through this tutorial:
http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html

I'm trying to select the axis2 Web Service facet (step 6) but I'm getting this error message in eclipse:
"Axis2 Web Services Core 1.1 requires Dynamic Web Module with version matching expression "2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5"

[image: screenshot]

Update: I had downloaded and installed axis2 1.5.4 and then in eclipse I went into "windows->preferences->web services->axis2 preferences". Under the "axis2 runtime" tab I specified the axis2 location. The message "Axis2 runtime loaded successfully" appeared.

[image: sreenshot2]

I don't know why it says "Axis2 Web Services Core 1.1". Does eclipse wtp come bundled with axis2 1.1 or is there a separate version # for the axis core from the overall axis version #?

Comment: Did you try changing the version of Dynamic web module from 3.0 to 2.5?

Comment: Do you know why it says axis core version 1.1 when I installed axis version 1.5.4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Yasin - you were right, it was merely a mater of changing the Dynamic web module to a previous version. I wasn't aware that the earlier versions had also been installed.

I'd give you credit for the answer, but since you just left a comment I just up-voted your comment.

Comment: I am locked into "Dynamic Web Module 3.0" so there is no way of downgrading and I can not select the Axis2 facet because of this error. Is there any way to upgrade the Axis2 Web Services Core 1.1 to something higher that accepts Dyn Web Mod 3.0?

Answer (score 9):

Change the Dynamic web module version to lower.

I used  java 1.5 and
         Dynamic web module version-3.0 So its raised an error. Then I changed the version 2.5. Now its not showing any error

Answer (score 1):

when I switched it to a lower version. It says

> cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 2.5

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should select project web module version to 2.5 or lower during the initial creation of the project. If you do it later, it won't accept it and cause an error.

Comment: Actually you can change the project web module version when you need to as long as it matches the other requirements